# Continue Dialog in Bot Framework C#

Tags: c#, azure, dialog, botframework, chatbot

I want to check if the user input and if it was (hello) to start a dialog and continue all the dialog flow but whenever I input the hello message and the flow start the first input to the bot will not go to the dialog it will go back to the OnTurn message and the dialog stop so I want a way to check if the dialog is active and continue it and if not just skip it.

```
public override async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var text = turnContext.Activity.Text;
        if (text == "hello")
        {
            await Dialog.RunAsync(turnContext, ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)), cancellationToken);
        }
        else 
        {
            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("dialog is not running");
        }
        await base.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);

        // Save any state changes that might have occurred during the turn.
        await ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
    }
```

as you can see in the code above in the else statement after the user input hello and then it will say that dialog is not running. how can I let the bot continue the dialog if there is one active.

Answer (score 0):

Need to save the current changes. It was missing in the code block currently. Try to replace it.

```
public override async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    await base.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);

    // Save any state changes that might have occurred during the turn.
    await ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
    await UserState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
var text = turnContext.Activity.Text;
        if (text == "hello")
        {
            await Dialog.RunAsync(turnContext, ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)), cancellationToken);
        }
        else 
        {
            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("waiting for dailog");
        }
        await base.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);

}

protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Logger.LogInformation("Running dialog with Message Activity.");

    // Run the Dialog with the new message Activity.
    await Dialog.RunAsync(turnContext, ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)), cancellationToken);
}
```